# i'm getting error 500 when i'm trying to perform a function in swagger CodGen

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restful, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I'm trying to build an API and I'm using swagger editor, swagger gen and swagger UI. I have a YAML file from swagger editor, and I generated a python-flask server, I ran the server and it worked fine, the problem is on my page I have a few endpoints when I want to try the endpoint I just press try it now button on the page and press execute and this is the response I keep getting
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm0rH.png)

what the response should be
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKm9i.png)

till now I didn't perform any logic for it i'm just trying to print on the server response but i keep getting the same error message

when I figured it out it was because of an error on the controller function of that specific endpoint, and this is what I have tried to print but I keep getting the same error above, i know it's because of that endpoint function but I don't know what exactly
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMKU4.png)

and this what I'm getting on the terminal
[[error on the terminal]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEIy4.png)

i even have tried this but same error
[second try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohsgr.png)

any solutions? or why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in your code and debug your application step by step and you might find the reason of the error.

Comment: i'm very new to swagger and flask, but what i have notice that the argument doesn't pass, the error tell me that the argument is missing but in my code it isn't